# Generate convex polygons from rectangles

Tags: javascript, geometry, polygon, convex

I am currently working on a 2D lighting system for a game. The maps are composed of tiles which can have certain tags and traits. In this case I have set some tiles as "opaque" and written a function to generate a bunch of rectangles for each opaque tile. I would like to optimize this geometry by merging large groups of rectangles into convex polygons.

My rectangles are defined as a collection of line segments in an array.

Example of a rectangle polygon:

```
var polygon = [
{a:{x:0,y:0}, b:{x:640,y:0}},
{a:{x:640,y:0}, b:{x:640,y:360}},
{a:{x:640,y:360}, b:{x:0,y:360}},
{a:{x:0,y:360}, b:{x:0,y:0}}];
```

So my question is how can I generate a smaller group of convex polygons from a large group of rectangles? I am by no means an expert coder so please include a thorough explanation in your answer as well as an example if you can. I have spent more than a few hours trying to figure this out on my own.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `O(n^2)` algorithm for your problem, all the introductory info you need is at this [topcoder article](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/line-sweep-algorithms/), I'm sure that if you use the line sweep algorithm to find sets of rectangles that intersect then the solution's time complexity will be `O(n log n)`

Main idea: create a set of group of rectangles then for each element of the set compute a convex hull

Let `n` be the number of groups, initially `n = 0`

1. take a rectangle `a` from your set (if it's member of some group skip to the next one, if there are no more rectangles that don't have a group then process the set of group of rectangles, more on this later)
2. Mark `a` as a member of the group `n`, try to intersect `a` with every other unvisited rectangle, when you find an intersection with the rectangle `b` then recursively run 2 with `b`
3. You'll have all the rectangles that are part of the group `n` which will be processed later, let `n = n + 1` and rerun 1 (this algorithm is called dfs by the way)
4. Now that each rectangle is assigned to it's own group run convex hull on the group, the output will be `n` convex polygons

The implementation it look something like this

```
// input
var rectangles = [ ... ];

function dfs(a, group, n) {
  assignRectangleToGroup(a, n)
  group.push(a)
  rectangles.forEach(function (b) {
    if ( rectangleDoesntHaveGroup(b) &&
        rectangleIntersects(a, b)) {
      dfs(b, group, n)
    }
  })
}

function generateConvexPolygons() {
  var n = 0;
  var set = []
  rectangles.forEach(function (a) {
    if (rectangleDoesntHaveGroup(a)) {
      var group = []
      dfs(a, group, n)
      set.push(group)
      n += 1
    }
  })

  return set.map(function (group) {
    return convexHull(group)
  })
}
```